# Realistic usage of unrolled skip lists

Tags: data-structures, linked-list, skip-lists

Why there is no any information in Google / Wikipedia about **unrolled skip list**? e.g. combination between unrolled linked list and skip list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably because it wouldn't typically give you much of a performance improvement, if any, and it would be somewhat involved to code correctly.

First, the unrolled linked list typically uses a pretty small node size. As the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unrolled_linked_list) says: " just large enough so that the node fills a single cache line or a small multiple thereof." On modern Intel processors, a cache line is 64 bytes. Skip list nodes have, *on average*, two pointers per node, which means an average of 16 bytes per node for the forward pointers. Plus whatever the data for the node is: 4 or 8 bytes for a scalar value, or 8 bytes for a reference (I'm assuming a 64 bit machine here).

So figure 24 bytes, total, for an "element."  Except that the elements aren't fixed size. They have a varying number of forward pointers. So you either need to make each element a fixed size by allocating an array for the maximum number of forward pointers for each element (which for a skip list with 32 levels would require 256 bytes), or use a dynamically allocated array that's the correct size. So your element becomes, in essence:

```
struct UnrolledSkipListElement
{
    void* data; // 64-bit pointer to data item
    UnrolledSkipListElement* forward_pointers; // dynamically allocated
}
```

That would reduce your element size to just 16 bytes. But then you lose much of the cache-friendly behavior that you got from unrolling. To find out where you go next, you have to dereference the `forward_pointers` array, which is going to incur a cache miss, and therefore eliminate the savings you got by doing the unrolling. In addition, that dynamically allocated array of pointers isn't free: there's some (small) overhead involved in allocating that memory.

If you can find some way around that problem, you're still not going to gain much. A big reason for unrolling a linked list is that you *must* visit every node (up to the node you find) when you're searching it. So any time you can save with each link traversal adds up to very big savings. But with a skip list you make large jumps. In a perfectly organized skip list, for example, you could skip half the nodes on the first jump (if the node you're looking for is in the second half of the list). If your nodes in the unrolled skip list only contain four elements, then the only savings you gain will be at levels 0, 1, and 2. At higher levels you're skipping more than three nodes ahead and as a result you will incur a cache miss.

So the skip list isn't unrolled because it would be somewhat involved to implement and it wouldn't give you much of a performance boost, if any. And it might very well cause the list to be slower.

Comment: hmm, probably is not because of this. you could do dynamic array and allocate only pointers you need? I also imagine there must be only one "group" of pointers per node.

Comment: But if you do a dynamic array and only allocate the pointers you need, then you're losing much, perhaps most, of the cache-friendly behavior that makes unrolling attractive.

Comment: not sure what you are saying. I call dynamic array when you have   void **x and then you do x = realloc / malloc(number_of_elements * sizeof(void *));

Comment: Thanks I will accept the answer. I think that unrolled linked list can be built with lots of elements too - say 1024 or more. Then, you will be able to jump from one node to the next and employ bin search inside the node. However even then, the "unrolled skip list" will be slower.

Answer (score 0):

**Linked list complexity is O(N)**

**Skip list complexity is O(Log N)**

Unrolled Linked List complexity can be calculate as following:

O (N / (M / 2) + Log M) = O (2N/M + Log M)

Where M is number of elements in single node.

Because Log M is not significant,

**Unrolled Linked List complexity is O(N/M)**

If we suppose to combine Skip list with Unrolled linked list, the new complexity will be

**O(Log N + "something from unrolled linked list such N1/M")**

This means the "new" complexity will not be as better as first someone will think. New complexity might be even worse than original O(Log N). The implementation will more complex as well. So gain is questionable and rather dubious.

Also, since single node will have lots of data, but only single "forward" array, the "tree" will not be so-balanced either and this will ruin O(Log N) part of the equation.